# mpirun hangs after program completion

Tags: mpi, openmpi

When I run the following command, I get the expected output but the program does not terminate immediately.

```
$ mpirun -np 2 echo 1
1
1
```

The program does not respond to interrupts either. Only after a minute or so I get back to the shell.

Or differently put: the program `mpirun -np 2 echo 1; echo 'done'` runs successfully but takes forever.

**Update**:
I ran `strace mpirun -np 2 echo 1`

The program hangs here:

```
sysinfo({uptime=5064793, loads=[153856, 184128, 229600], totalram=67362279424, freeram=26006364160, sharedram=8040448, bufferram=1739857920, totalswap=34359734272, freeswap=34358018048, procs=309, totalhigh=0, freehigh=0, mem_unit=1}) = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="euler", ...}) = 0
ioctl(13, _IOC(0, 0, 0x25, 0)
```

and then here:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/openmpi-sessions-216211@euler_0/42701", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
munmap(0x7f61ed88c000, 2127408)         = 0
munmap(0x7f61ee0a1000, 2101720)         = 0
close(9)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f61ede9e000, 2105664)         = 0
munmap(0x7f61ed685000, 2122480)         = 0
munmap(0x7f61eda95000, 2109856)         = 0
munmap(0x7f61ed47c000, 2130304)         = 0
munmap(0x7f61ed05b000, 2109896)         = 0
munmap(0x7f61ecc9a000, 3934648)         = 0
munmap(0x7f61ed25f000, 2212016)         = 0
munmap(0x7f61ec8e3000, 3894144)         = 0
munmap(0x7f61ec6bd000, 2248968)         = 0
munmap(0x7f61ea776000, 28999696)        = 0
munmap(0x7f61edc99000, 2110072)         = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Could you help me debug this further?

Comment: Which version of Open MPI is that?

Comment: `$ mpirun --version`: `mpirun (Open MPI) 2.1.1`

Comment: This is on `uname -a`: `Linux euler 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Now, I compiled OpenMPI `3.1.4` and the program successfully terminates immediately.

Comment: if you have any firewall running, try to disable it.

Comment: I updated the question to include some log messages. I'll check the firewall status with the system administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the NVIDIA driver was broken. Updating the driver to `440.64.00` resolved the issue.